# Do a default save rather than override

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=160, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=create_user_image_path,
                               validators=[validate_avatar],
                               default="default/avatars/default.jpg")
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.avatar:
            image = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
            image_path = self.avatar.path
            image_name = self.avatar.path[:-4]
            image_ext = self.avatar.path[-4:]

            resize_images(image, image_path, image_name, image_ext)
            image.close()
```

The model also has its default save method overridden to do some logic for the image that's uploaded. However, let's say the user signed up and has no image, so the default image is used instead. So when this happens `Profile(user=22).save()` I don't want to use the overridden save method because we are using the default image instead, so there's no extra logic needed. Is there a way I can save it normally in the database instead of it going through the overridden save method?

Comment: Please, share your own `save()` method.

Comment: @HuLuViCa Updated question. Save method will take and resize the image uploaded, but the image is already resized for the default image, so this logic doesn't need to be executed

Comment: Isn't that what the `if self.avatar:` line is for? If the profile doesn't have an avatar, it won't run the code inside.

Comment: @GrandPhuba Yes, but for some reason it's still executing `self.avatar`

Comment: Have you debbuged your code? Are you sure of the value of `self.avatar` after calling `super()`?. Maybe it would work if you call `super()` after `if` evaluation.

Comment: @HuLuViCa so self.avatar will be the default value when it goes in the save method, so it always have a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rob Vezina got the question right with his answer.

That being said, the ideal way of doing what you are really trying to do is is keeping the `avatar` field blank, and show the default image in the templates if the profile has no uploaded `avatar`.

```
<img src={{ user.profile.avatar.url|default:'/static/default_avatar.jpg' }} />
<!-- better if you have the URL of the default image stored as a constant in your code -->
```

or

```
class Profile(models.Model
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        storage=OverwriteStorage(), 
        upload_to=create_user_image_path,
        validators=[validate_avatar]
    )

    def image(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.avatar.url if self.avatar else '/static/default_avatar.jpg'  # Even better if you have this literal string as a constant in your settings
```

```
<img src={{ user.image }} />
```

The advantages of these solutions are:

1. You don't have to change it in the database when you want to change the default image
2. You maintain a record of profiles with no uploaded avatars

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a default value, your conditional `if self.avatar` is always going to be true. You need to check the value of self.avatar to see if it's the default.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.avatar.name != Profile._meta.get_field('avatar').get_default():
            image = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
            image_path = self.avatar.path
            image_name = self.avatar.path[:-4]
            image_ext = self.avatar.path[-4:]

            resize_images(image, image_path, image_name, image_ext)
            image.close()
```